# Crop a raster file in R

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, africa

I have a UN-Adjusted Population Count dataset, for the year 2015, stored in a TIFF file format (~450MB) downloaded from http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/collection/gpw-v4/sets/browse

In R I am able to read the data using raster package. I am also able to plot it as follows,

```
#read your TIFF file

worldpopcount <- raster("gpw-v4-population-count-adjusted-to-2015-unwpp-country-totals_2015.tif")

worldpopcount

plot(worldpopcount)
```

Now I want to crop the West African region (covering the three countries Guinea, Liberia and Sierra Leone). My coordinates for West Africa are,

```
# extent format (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)

# WestBound     -16
# EastBound      -7.25
# SouthBound      4
# NorthBound     12.75
```

How do I crop the data using extent/crop? Once the region of interest has been cropped I would like to export it to an asc (ESRI ASCII) using the code

```
#writeRaster(r, filename="westAfrica.asc", format = "ascii", datatype='INT4S', overwrite=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a box as a Spatial object and crop your raster by the box.

```
e <- as(extent(-16, -7.25, 4, 12.75), 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(e) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
r <- crop(worldpopcount, e)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [`raster`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) package documentation,

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrow=45, ncol=90)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)

# crop Raster* with Spatial* object
b <- as(extent(6, 6.4, 49.75, 50), 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(b) <- crs(r)
rb <- crop(r, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a shapefile:

```
library(raster)

my_shape <- shapefile("../Input/area1.shp")
my_raster <- raster("../Input/raster_band1.tif")

r2 <- crop(my_raster, extent(my_shape)) ### crop to the extent
my_raster_clip <- mask(x= r2, mask=my_shape) ### delimitation to the shape geometry

plot(my_raster_clip)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23074167/14361772